# Android ImageView causing whitespace at the bottom

Tags: android, xml, imageview

My code below is causing a whitespace at the bottom of the image. I wanted the image to cover the entire screen, but somehow it isn't.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ohm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/test2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/night"
        android:src="@drawable/night"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/night"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
        android:textColor="#D69E29"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:hint="USERNAME"
        android:textColorHint="#D69E29"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
        android:textColor="#D69E29"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:hint="PASSWORD"
        android:textColorHint="#D69E29"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've tried changing to different `scaleType` but it is still the same. Then, if I change the `adjustViewBounds` to false, the image will become double in height.

Below images are the 2 issues I am facing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4fan.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUIXM.png

Comment: You want drawable/ohm cover all your screen? then try to set it as background, not src.

Comment: @Minhtdh I tried your solution, but it still doesn't solve the issue. Setting it to background only making the image longer and not fit to the screen.

Comment: Have you tried to set it as background of the scrollView or set as bg of imageview and also remove adjustViewBound? You use adjustViewBound and scaleType=centerCrop, so of course the drawable keep it ratio and can not fullscreen

Comment: @Minhtdh I have added 2 images to my question. The 2 images show the issues I am facing with different settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue. I create a Layout and put the ScrollView inside it, then create another Layout inside the ScrollView. I'm not sure if this is a good or bad practice, but it seems to be a solution for now. Will need some experts to view the solution.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ohm">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem before, my solution is to use the image which have the same width:height ratio with the screen.

Comment: But I need it to be viewable in any devices. The aspect ratio should remain for tablets and smartphones.

Comment: Yeah, I choose the image with the ratio ~1.67 will work on almost screen. It will scale to fit.

I remember my bug in nexus 9 (4:3 screen ratio) the image will be shrunk.

Comment: And for some special ratio screens, you can manually set the image source in the code behind.

Comment: There must be a way to code the xml instead of just changing the image size. Or maybe not? hmmm